How can I return a constexpr std::array from a function?
There are 14998 palindromic numbers in [1, 50000000).
I want to define a function that finds them out at compile-time, populates an std::array<int, 14998> and returns it.
I have an idea but cannot compile it. What am I doing wrong ?
#include <array>

bool is_valid(int src)noexcept {
    auto ret{ 0 }, cpy{ src };
    do {
        ret = ret * 10 + src % 10;
    } while ((src /= 10) != 0);
    return ret == cpy;
}

std::array<int, 14998> constexpr build()noexcept {
    std::array<int, 14998> ret{};
    for (auto i{ 1 }, j{ -1 }; i != 50000000; ++i) {
        if (is_valid(i)) {
            ret[++j] = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    auto constexpr lut{ build() };
    return 0;
}


Always post complete error along with your question.

is_valid is not a contexpr function so how do you expect it to be usable in giving a constexpr result.

Also use constexpr if instead of just if.

Additionally, function parameters are not constexpr.

@user12002570 Here you are: expression (auto constexpr lut{ build() };) did not evaluate to a constant (Compiler Error C2131).

error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘bool is_valid(int)’

If you are using MSVC, add constexpr to bool is_valid() and try these options: /std:c++latest /constexpr:steps50000000

@kakkoko Yes, it is MSVC. I have added constexpr to is_valid but unfortunately it does not compile and the same error occurs. Since this is part from competitive programming problem solution of which i send to an online judge i cannot add any options.

If you added constexpr bool is_valid(int src)noexcept, then your error should change to an ‘constexpr’ loop iteration count exceeds limit error. Are you saying you cannot change the definition of is_valid() in your code?

@David C. Rankin I have added constexpr to is_valid but unfortunately it does not compile and the same error occurs in MSVC but if i send to the online judge the error changes to ./solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: ./solution.cpp:22:31: in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘build()’ ./solution.cpp:13:5: error: ‘constexpr’ loop iteration count exceeds limit of 262144 (use ‘-fconstexpr-loop-limit=’ to increase the limit) 13 | for (auto i{ 1 }, j{ -1 }; i != 50000000; ++i) { | ^~~

@David C. Rankin When I double click on C2131 in VS I can read that failure was caused by evaluation exceeding step limit of 1048576 (/constexpr:steps).

@PetarIvanov The error message is clear. If this is for a competitive programming problem, then you are not meant to try to do all the work at compile time instead of actually solving the problem normally.

@Unmitigated I have already solved it but I want to change the design. The task is to answer how many palindromic number there are in [a, b], and what is the minimum and maximum differences between them. This is just a precalculation of an array which I will do some binary search in.

There is something fishy with the logic, or you really do need to provide the /constexpr:steps50000000 option or similar. I'm not convinced that will do it. At least on gcc that still throws an error at 33554432. (using -fconstexpr-loop-limit=50000000) -- which itself is a bit odd.

You have several issues:

is_valid(int src) is not constexpr
You reach the compiler limit

Compilers provide flag to set internal limit.
You might use alternative algorithm to build the table though:
constexpr int pow_10(int n) {
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        res *= 10;
    }
    return res;
}

static_assert(pow_10(0) == 1);
static_assert(pow_10(1) == 10);
static_assert(pow_10(2) == 100);

constexpr std::pair<int, int> get_rev_pow(int n)
{
    int rev = 0;
    int pow = 1;

    while (n != 0) {
        rev = rev * 10 + n % 10;
        pow *= 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return {rev, pow};
}

static_assert(get_rev_pow(1) == std::pair{1, 10});
static_assert(get_rev_pow(10) == std::pair{1, 100});

enum class Parity : bool
{
    Even, Odd
};

constexpr int create_palyndrome(int n, Parity p)
{
    const auto [rev, pow] = get_rev_pow(n);
    switch (p) {
        case Parity::Odd: return rev + (n / 10) * pow;
        default:
        case Parity::Even: return rev + n * pow;
    }
}

static_assert(create_palyndrome(1, Parity::Odd) == 1);
static_assert(create_palyndrome(1, Parity::Even) == 11);
static_assert(create_palyndrome(10, Parity::Odd) == 101);

std::array<int, 14998> constexpr build()noexcept {
    std::array<int, 14998> ret{};

    std::size_t j = 0;
    for (int s = 1; s != 5; ++s) {
        int i_max = pow_10(s);
        for (auto p : {Parity::Odd, Parity::Even}) {
            for (int i = pow_10(s - 1); i != i_max; ++i) {
                ret[j++] = create_palyndrome(i, p);
                if (j == ret.size()) return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

Demo

No mate, the problem is not the solution. I have already solved it. Check this out. The time limit is 2100 ms. My CPU time is 444 ms. I want to move the //0 phase to compile time but it is impossible to do so because I cannot give compiler options to the judge system.

I built the same table as you at compile time, but using different way.
